# Why less won't be displayed during the execution of a command substitution?

Tags: bash, less, command-substitution

I have an interactive script that returns a path for `cd` to use in the parent process. Like this:

```
$ cd $(myscript)
```

During the execution of the script, I want to be able to display some information in `less`. Unfortunately, using `less` during a command substitution seems not to work :

```
$ echo $(less <<< 'some text') # Not working
some text
```

So my questions : why is it not working ?
Is there a work around ?

I'm trying to display an interactive help screen during the execution of the script. And I need that script to be in a command substitution as it is my only way to cd to the path yielded in the parent process. Might be a better way to do that but that is my best bet so far.

Comment: It is still not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

In general, `echo $(somecmd)` isn't very useful, for any `somecmd`. The output from `somecmd` would be expanded to the arguments of `echo`, and then `echo` would take its arguments and print them to its output. Usually, you could just directly run `somecmd` instead.

The difference between those two being the usual: word-splitting and globbing. `echo $(somecmd)` will compress whitespace and expand anything that looks like a filename glob (`*.txt`). These of course won't happen when running just `somecmd` or when running `echo "$(somecmd)"` with the quotes, though *that* removes all but the last newline. there's also the chance that your `echo` expands backslash-escapes.

As for `less`, its purpose is to allow *interactive* browsing of a file or pipe input, and that pretty much requires a terminal. When you run it in a command substitution, `less`'s output is connected to a pipe instead, and it falls back to behaving pretty much like `cat`. (Seems to, I can't find a mention of the exact behavior in the man page.)

---

Now, if you seriously need a script that runs inside a command substitution, allowing the user to browse some output, and still returning some other text through the command substitution, you could do some creative use of redirections (paraphrasing mosvy's comment):

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash
echo this is the output

cat >&2 <<EOF
you can
browse this
with less
EOF
$ foo=$( ./myscript 2> >(less > /dev/tty))
```

The script's standard output goes to the command substitution and its error output to `less`, so `foo` gets set to `this is the output`. I'm not sure if this is useful in any way, since you won't be able to modify the value going to `foo` interactively, at least not with just `less`.

Also, running `less` like that messes with job control, so hitting Ctrl-C when it's running produces weird behaviour etc.

---

Here, it would probably be better to just use a temporary file. Have `myscript` write the result to a file named as an argument (i.e. `echo "$result" > "$1"`), then run:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
myscript "$tmp"
cd "$(cat "$tmp")"
rm "$tmp"
```

Now `myscript` can launch `less` or another interactive program in the normal way, and there shouldn't be issues with job control.

Comment: great answer, thx. It is indeed messing with job control. So I guess I need to use trap to avoid that.

Comment: @ogr, there is also the option of using a temporary file instead of a direct command substitution.

Comment: @ikkachu indeed, that would probably be the safest option here. I'd like to avoid passing additional parameters to the script in my particular case however.

Comment: @ogr, sure, it's not as straightforward. If it's just the extra argument, you could have a hard-coded temp file (with the associated problems) or pass the name through the environment (which really isn't that different from an argument, though)

Answer (score 3):

```
(trap : INT; echo "$(less <<< 'some text' >/dev/tty; echo done)")
```

`less` will devolve into a kind of (un)fancy `cat` when its stdout is not a tty, as when used in a command substitution (where its stdout is a pipe) [1].

When testing in an interactive bash (where the job control is enabled by default), the `(...)` subshell will make sure that that the `less` command is run as part of a proper foreground job in the terminal, without which it may not be possible to suspend it with `^Z`, terminate it with `^C` and it will misbehave in other ways [2].

The `trap : INT` will cause the subshell to ignore a `^C`, without passing that disposition to its childen.

If the command is part of a shell script, all the processes will be run as part of the same process group / job, but the `(...)` may still be useful to limit the scope of the `INT` trap.

[1] You cannot even use it to print binary data nicely escaped when its stdout is not a tty:

```
$ printf '\xee' | less -FXR
<EE>
$ printf '\xee' | less -FXR | cat
�$
```

[2] There are many possible scenarios for what may happen, all bad. For instance, in

```
$ ls -d $(less <<<'some text' >/dev/tty; pwd)
```

`bash` will fork a separate process in which to exec the `ls` binary, and will run the `$(...)` process substitution as a child of it *before* moving it into a separate process group / job and executing the binary.

When you press `^Z` inside `less`, it will be handled by `less` normally, but will either fail to stop it (if the shell and consequently `less`'s job is the session leader), or will cause only `less`, but not its parent process to stop.

When you press `^C` inside `less`, it will caught and handled by `less`, but a `SIGINT` will also be sent to the main shell (which is foreground job on the terminal), which will cause it to return the next prompt, and the bash's readline and `less` to compete for input and change the terminal properties unaware of each other, resulting in a complete cockup.

**Note**

All this applies to *any* program run from a command substitution, not just to the `$(less ...)` example, eg.

```
$ cat >foo <<'EOT'; chmod 755 foo
t=$(mktemp)
vi "$t" </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1
echo "$t"
EOT
$ cat $(./foo)
# ^Z doesn't work in vi
```

Comment: Nice ! 
It works, but I don't really understand why. `the (...) subshell will make sure that that the less command is run as part of the foreground job in the terminal,`. How does that happens ? (I'm not super familiar with process group)
Also, any reason I should use trap here ? Will it misbehave without it ?

Comment: @ogr I've added some description -- this is by no way exhaustive, and may change from one version of bash to another.

Comment: Thx for the follow up. It's more clear for me now.